# CMake not findng include directories for OpenSSL projects

Tags: cmake, build, openssl

I am remaking the post because i have made a bit of progress since i last made it. First of all i am learning cmake and would like to make a project i had already made before using cmake. This is what my directory should look like.
[image]

In the OpenSSL cmakelists.txt i wrote the script to find openssl installation or install it if it is not installed:

```
# check if OpenSSL is already installed in the system - using CMake's built in script FindOpenSSL
find_package(OpenSSL QUIET)

if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found preinstalled OpenSSL libraries at ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
    add_library(OpenSSL_external INTERFACE)

    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR})
else()
    message(STATUS "Preinstalled OpenSSL library not found")
    message(STATUS "Will now download and install OpenSLL in ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

    include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(OpenSSL_external
        GIT_REPOSITORY
        https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git 
        GIT_TAG 
        OpenSSL_1_1_1u  
        UPDATE_COMMAND 
        "" 
        CMAKE_ARGS 
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${STAGE_INSTALL_PREFIX} 
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} 
     
        TEST_AFTER_INSTALL 
        0 
        DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS 
        1 
        LOG_CONFIGURE 
        1 
        LOG_BUILD 
        1 
        LOG_INSTALL 
        1 
    )

    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX})
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}" OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR)
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "OpenSLL installation dir")
endif()
```

The source directory cmaketestlists.txt defines the variables for the locaation of the openssl include and lib directories

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(File_Encrypter_core LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)

set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCES main.cpp)

if(APPLE)
    # create bundle on apple compiles
    add_executable(main MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SOURCES})

    # set custom plist file for the app bundle - needed for Mac OS Retina display
    set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist)
endif()

if(WIN32)
    # create bundle on windows compiles
    add_executable("main" ${SOURCES})
endif()

target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}/include)

target_link_directories(main PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}/lib)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

And the root directory cmaketestlist.txt sets everything up

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(File_Encrypter)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 11)

# ExternalProject base
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY EP_BASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subprojects)

set(STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/stage)

add_subdirectory(thirdparty)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(${PROJECT_NAME}_core
    DEPENDS
        OpenSSL_external
    SOURCE_DIR
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    
        -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    BUILD_ALWAYS
        1
    INSTALL_COMMAND
        ""
    )
```

The thirdparty one just includes the openssl directory. Generating the build file with `cmake -S. -Bbuild` is functional and does not give eerors. But when i try to compile the .exe i get the error saying that it could not find the location for openssl/evp.h which is the first include in the main.cpp. I am going to assume it is the same for all the header files that i used when making the main.cpp. I have no idea how to fix as i have been figuring out this whole endeavour for the 8 hours. Please help. I have provided more context in this edit for the veterans to have more info to work with

Comment: The error message contains the exact invocation which is failed. Have you tried to run it from the command line? That way you may got more detailed information about the errors. Also, Stack Overflow discourages **images** which just contain textual information (build log in your case): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. Instead, paste the text directly into the question post.

Comment: I have removed the picture. But what do you mean the exact incovation that failed. I went to the cmake file and found this code. I will add it to the question

Comment: Invocation comes after the line `Command failed: 1`.

Comment: After your comment i realised that i do indeed have OpenSSL installed but it wasnt detecting it. Maybe it was because i didnt use the default path. So i reinstalled it and now it detects it. So it is not giving me that error anymore but it is giving me errors in my CMakeLists.txt file.
```
'CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
    Cannot find source file:

      main.exe.manifest

    Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
    .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc'
```

Comment: If you want us to help you in fixing new error (`Cannot find source file`), then you need to update the question post with details about that error and your code which causes it.